# Remote rejected

Tags: git, repository

I have the error "Remote rejected (Working directory has unstaged changes)".
The error happens when I want to push my first changes, after cloning the repository. Please note that we have other repositories on the same platform and I can make changes without problem.

The error persist with an specific repository.

The steps I am doing are:

1. ```
    Git clone [URL]
   ```
2. ```
    Make changes (add file)
   ```
3. ```
    Git add .
   ```
4. ```
    Git commit –m “message”
   ```
5. ```
    Git push origin master
   ```
6. ```
    Add password
   ```
7. ```
    The password is accepted, but the following error appears:
   ```

! [remote rejected] master -> master (Working directory has unstaged changes)
error: failed to push some refs to [URL repository]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You have uncommitted changes locally, stash them first.

```
git stash
```

After you've pushed, get your stashed changes back

```
git stash pop
```

Comment: Although I have done commit and then git statsh I get the following message:
"No local changes to save"

Comment: what comes up when you do a `git status`?

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: and `git push` doesn't work now?

Comment: I finally solved the problem. There was difference between the files on the server and my local one. So, I did git reset --hard HEAD, then cloned the repo, made changes and push again. Everything is fine now. :)
Thanks @MikeSchem

Comment: glad you got it working @Corina